# Cron-based terminal job doesn't start until screen unlocked (sometimes)

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-3, terminal, cron

I have a cron job whose command line looks like:

```
30 5 * * * osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "bash-script-file"'
```

FWIW the base script file sets some environment variables and then runs a Ruby program.

Prior to last week, most days this ran just fine, but occasionally (~ twice/month) it would hang until I either unlocked the screen or attached remotely to the system. At that time I would see a terminal screen with a message about new mail and a command line prompt with the bash-script-file on it. At that point, I could wait and the script would proceed to run normally. I have checked System Settings and the computer is set to sleep never. I'm not locking the screen (instead allowing it to go to sleep), and of course I have the screen saver locked, requiring a password to wake up.

Last week (about five days ago), I added a second cron job of the same form (running another bash script that started another Ruby program), and since then, both jobs have hung every day until I attached remotely. What is causing this? What can I do to resolve it?

tl;dr cron-scheduled terminal jobs are hanging until the screen unlocks.

Comment: Do you need to run the scripts in Terminal, or can they just run directly? I don't know the details, but I can easily see why having a GUI program (Terminal) involved would cause something like this.

Comment: The main reason for running in a terminal is for troubleshooting. From time to time strange errors occur.

Comment: Scanning SO before posting this, the only article I found was about this happening when someone did a fast user switch to lock the screen instead of letting the screen saver lock the screen, and I get that that would be an issue, but this is not that.

Comment: I found an article talking about running screen directly (e.g. "/usr/bin/screen -dm script-file-name"), but when I try that I get “Must run suid root for multiuser support”. Found another article for that error saying to "chmod u+s /usr/bin/screen" but got "chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/bin/screen: Operation not permitted". I tried "sudo chmod ..." but got the same message. So now I'm stumped.